# Search data for a period of time using date format

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search data from my MySQL table 'inverter' for a specific period of time. In the page I have used a java datepicker that returns a value in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. In the database table the dates are stored in the format `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss`.

I have used the query:

```
$query= ("SELECT * FROM inverter WHERE id= '".$_POST['mac']."' AND DATE_FORMAT(cur_timestamp,\"%m/%d/%Y\" ) BETWEEN '".$_POST['select1']."' AND '".$_POST['select2']."'");
```

where `select1` and `select2` are the two `datepickers`. 
The code is running fine for a single date. It is also showing the input dates.

After compilation and Query being displayed on the page, output is:

```
SELECT * FROM inverter WHERE machine_id= '1111' AND DATE_FORMAT(cur_timestamp,"%m/%d/%Y" ) BETWEEN '11/01/2013' AND '01/06/2014'
```

Please help.

Comment: And what error or problem you are facing?

Comment: Data is not fetched in case of two datepickers

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ You really can't tell?

Comment: Clearly, you have to modify the picker to return appropriate values. '2013-01-11','2014-01-06'. Also, a useful tip when providing sample dates for review by other is to confine those samples to dates beyond the 12th of the month. Otherwise confusion reigns.

Comment: If the date_format is working for a single datepicker why it is not working for two datepickers? The only difference in the entire code is this query.

Comment: @user3165121 try my answer as I have posted.

Comment: I just discovered one thing. The codes are working fine with 2013 dates. When I am giving 2014 dates, the codes are not working.

Comment: Can anyone help me out? The codes are not working when I am inputting 2014 dates. Else, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a possible way only because I am not sure which will work for you.

first try this:

```
$query= ("SELECT * FROM inverter WHERE id= '".$_POST['mac']."' AND DATE_FORMAT(cur_timestamp,\"%m/%d/%Y\" ) > '".$_POST['select1']."' AND  DATE_FORMAT(cur_timestamp,\"%m/%d/%Y\" ) < '".$_POST['select2']."'");
```

Second one is try this:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['select1']));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['select2']));

$query= ("SELECT * FROM inverter WHERE id= '".$_POST['mac']."' AND DATE(cur_timestamp) > '".$date1."' AND DATE(cur_timestamp) < '".$date2."'");
```